# session not destroyed after browser closed

Tags: php, session

i have two pages with session:

p1.php

```
<?php
session_name("dsdad09d8sahd");
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo "<br>";
echo $_SESSION["name"] = "MADRID";
```

p2.php

```
<?php
session_name("dsdad09d8sahd");
echo session_id();
echo "<br>";
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["name"];
```

when i open first and second page in private browser the code work fine but after closing private browser and open again  the session will not be destroyed why ??

Comment: normally after closing private browser the session should be destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

You are telling your client to use a session id called `dsdad09d8sahd`. The session is retained on the server, even after clearing the cookie/session in the browser.

You are basically restoring the session with `session_name("dsdad09d8sahd");`